# Call viewController from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xib, pushviewcontroller

I have a .xib containing a bottom bar view.  It has a button that shows a view. I use that bottom bar in almost every view controller and I can't make it work even after searching for over two hours.

Clicking in the bottom bar is working fine (`NSLog` shows that the button actions are being called when I click them), but I can't find a way to do what I want. The button needs to show a `UITableViewController` with 6-7 rows in a specific frame so I don't want to fully use the screen.

```
|------|
|      |
|      |
|      |
|      |
|______|
|+_____|

|------|
|      |
|      |
|------|
| here |
|______|
|+_____|
```

In the above figure, the "+" sign is the button, and it needs to show the `UITableViewController` in the position marked "here" just above the bottom bar.

I'm new to iOS and I'm banging my head against a wall because of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several different ways to get this to work.  One is to use [child view controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).  A more idiomatic way is to use a `UIPopoverController`, although that has its own UI and offers you less control than doing it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UITableViewController expects to use the entire screen. I don't think it's what you want here.

I'd just create a UIView subclass and add a UITableView to it. You can then add your custom view to the current view as a subview. Your subclass can be the data source and delegate, so it can be completely self-contained so you can use it anywhere in the app. It can also be full-screen sized if you want to detect tapping outside of the table view to dismiss the custom view. Just make the backgroundColor clearColor and add a gesture recognizer to detect the tap.

Comment: Thank you really, you made me see this from another point of view and that worked perfectly. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have some better options for this than using an `UITableViewController` but nevertheless here goes:

You basically want to add a child view controller. It can be done like this (this will be in `Swift` but I can add an `ObjC` version too):

```
func buttonTap(sender: UIButton) {
    let viewController = UITableViewController(style: .Plain)
    viewController.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

    self.addChildViewController(viewController)
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, self.view.bounds.height * 0.5)
    self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

This is called creating a [container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) and is quite common (`UIPageViewController`, `UINavigationController`, ... all use this mechanism).

However since I don't really like `UITableViewControllers` I would recommend creating a simple `UITableView` and adding it as a subview. As for the `delegate` and `dataSource` both can be separated into separate classes (and files) so you can avoid a bloated implementation.